# Append to a DataFrame in Pandas as new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames with the same indexing and want to append the second to the first. Lets say I have:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], index = [2,3,4])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([3,5,3], index = [2,3,4])
df1 = df1.append(df2)
```

which returns

```
   0
2  1
3  2
4  3
2  3
3  5
4  3
```

But I want it to append a new column where the indexes match:

```
2  1  3
3  2  5
4  3  3
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding 2 data frame in python pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419952/adding-2-data-frame-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `concat` and pass param `axis=1` to concatenate the list of dfs column-wise:

```
In [3]:

df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], index = [2,3,4])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([3,5,3], index = [2,3,4])
pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
Out[3]:
   0  0
2  1  3
3  2  5
4  3  3
```

You can also use `join` but you have to rename the column first:

```
In [6]:

df1.join(df2.rename(columns={0:'x'}))
Out[6]:
   0  x
2  1  3
3  2  5
4  3  3
```

Or `merge` specifying that you wish to match on indices:

```
In [8]:

df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={0:'x'}), left_index=True, right_index=True )
Out[8]:
   0  x
2  1  3
3  2  5
4  3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

If the indexes match exactly and there's only one column in the other DataFrame (like your question has), then you could even just add the other DataFrame as a new column.

```
>>> df1['new_column'] = df2
>>> df1
   0  new_column
2  1           3
3  2           5
4  3           3
```

In general, the `concat` approach is better. If you have different indexes, you can choose to do an `inner join` or `outer join`.

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([3,5,3], index = [2,3,5])
>>> df2
   0
2  3
3  5
5  3

>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner')
   0  0
2  1  3
3  2  5

>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='outer')
    0   0
2   1   3
3   2   5
4   3 NaN
5 NaN   3
```